# How to add areas under a geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to display on the same graph a geom_line and the state (which is in a vector).

The data for example:

```
Timestamp;Value;State
20190618;1.2;UP
20190619;1.0;DOWN
20190620;1.1;UP
...
```

This is an example of what i'd like to obtain:

[image]

I know how to geom_line, i've already try to use geom_area but none of these try succeed.
Any help ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Timestamp, xmax = lead(Timestamp),
                ymin = 0, ymax = Inf,
                fill = State), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_step(aes(Timestamp, Value))
```

### [image]

```
# based on your data, after converting into table with Timestamp as a date
df <- structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(18065, 18066, 18067), class = "Date"), 
                Value = c(1.2, 1, 1.1), State = c("UP", "DOWN", "UP")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for (alternative to `geom_rect`)?

[image]

Prepare example data

```
x <- 1:5
y <- c(4,1,6,2,2)
plot.df <- data.frame(Timestamp=x, Value=y)
```

Code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot.df, aes(x=Timestamp,y=Value)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           alpha = .2, fill = "green") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 2, xmax = 3, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           alpha = .2, fill = "red") +
  annotate("rect", xmin = 3, xmax = 4, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
           alpha = .2, fill = "green") +
  geom_step(direction = "h") +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: My file can have many more lines, so i can't add all the "annotate" code foreach area. I want a code to generate all the area.